# Efficient ways to generate a matrix from multiplying two elements of some matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I am working on the single particle entanglement entropy and in the process I have something like

```
Table[
    Sum[
        states[[eindex, spaceindex]] * states[[eindex, spaceindex2]], 
        {eindex,1, Na/2}(*trace over lower-half filling*)
    ], 
    {spaceindex, 1, Nb}, 
    {spaceindex2, 1, Nb}(*some subsystem*)
]
```

where `states` is a `Na` by `Na` square matrix, from diagonalizing some other matrix. 1<`Nb`<`Na` is some sub-system. The matrix I am trying to construct is essentially $C_{i,j}=Tr[states[k,i]*states[k,j]]$ traced over the first index.

The above code gets the job done but I wonder if there are more efficient ways.

Also, I keep getting myself into this situation where I need to generate a matrix efficiently via similar constructions, for example, projection matrices. I would also like to know some general ways to directly translate the equations into efficient code.

Comment: Can you include a full example with all indices and variables defined, and the output you wish to obtain? It's difficult for me to follow your intentions from code that you yourself say is not optimal.

Comment: To contract 2 matrices a,b over the first index use e.g.  `Transpose[a].b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is your friend because these operations are run by highly optimized libraries (BLAS).

Read out the matrices first, `Transpose` one of them and then `Dot` them together:

```
n = 1000;
Nb = 500;
Na = 400;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];

ilist = Range[1, Nb];
jlist = Range[1, Nb];
klist = Range[1, Quotient[Na, 2]];

result0 = Table[Sum[A[[k, i]] A[[k, j]], {k, 1, Na/2}], {i, 1, Nb}, {j, 1, Nb}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

result = Transpose[A[[klist, ilist]]] . A[[klist, jlist]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

Max[Abs[result0 - result]]
```

> 28.7556
>
> 0.000697215
>
> 2.84217*10^-14

As you can see, this is 40000 times faster with negligible error (which stems from then fact that floating point additions is not really associative).